# Finding parent of child in breadth first search

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to find the parent of children in breadth first search, considering an unweighted,undirected graph the neighbours are easy to find but I don't get how can I print the parents along with the childs. Here is the code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bfs;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class BreadthFirstSearchExample
{ 

 private Queue<Node> queue;
 static ArrayList<Node> nodes=new ArrayList<Node>();
 static class Node
 {
  int data;
  boolean visited;

  Node(int data)
  {
   this.data=data;

  }
 }

 public BreadthFirstSearchExample()
 {
  queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
 }

 // find neighbors of node using adjacency matrix
 // if adjacency_matrix[i][j]==1, then nodes at index i and index j are connected
 public ArrayList<Node> findNeighbours(int adjacency_matrix[][],Node x)
 {
  int nodeIndex=-1;

  ArrayList<Node> neighbours=new ArrayList<Node>();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
   if(nodes.get(i).equals(x))
   {
    nodeIndex=i;
    break;
   }
  }

  if(nodeIndex!=-1)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < adjacency_matrix[nodeIndex].length; j++) {
    if(adjacency_matrix[nodeIndex][j]==1)
    {
     neighbours.add(nodes.get(j));
    }
   }
  }
  return neighbours;
 }

 public  void bfs(int adjacency_matrix[][], Node node)
 {
  queue.add(node);
  node.visited=true;
  int nf =0;
  while (!queue.isEmpty())
  {
   nf = queue.size();
   Node element=queue.remove();
   System.out.print(element.data + "\t");


   ArrayList<Node> neighbours=findNeighbours(adjacency_matrix,element);
   for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++) {
    Node n=neighbours.get(i);
    int mf = neighbours.size();

    if(n!=null && !n.visited)
    {
     queue.add(n);
     n.visited=true;
     //System.out.print("neighbours"+ n.data + "\t");
//     System.out.print("vertices" + nf + "\t");
//     System.out.print("degree" + mf + "\t");

    }
   }

  }
 }

 public static void main(String arg[])
 {

   Node node40 =new Node(40);
   Node node10 =new Node(10);
   Node node20 =new Node(20);
   Node node30 =new Node(30);
   Node node60 =new Node(60);
   Node node50 =new Node(50);
   Node node70 =new Node(70);

   nodes.add(node40);
   nodes.add(node10);
   nodes.add(node20);
   nodes.add(node30);
   nodes.add(node60);
   nodes.add(node50);
   nodes.add(node70);
   int adjacency_matrix[][] = {
     {0,1,1,0,0,0,0},  // Node 1: 40
     {1,0,0,1,0,0,0},  // Node 2 :10
     {1,0,0,1,1,1,0},  // Node 3: 20
     {0,1,1,0,1,0,0},  // Node 4: 30
     {0,0,1,1,0,0,1},  // Node 5: 60
     {0,0,1,0,0,0,1},  // Node 6: 50
     {0,0,0,0,1,1,0},  // Node 7: 70
   };
   System.out.println("The BFS traversal of the graph is ");
   BreadthFirstSearchExample bfsExample = new BreadthFirstSearchExample();
   bfsExample.bfs(adjacency_matrix, node40);

 }
}
```

The output is `40 10 20 30 60 50 70`

I want the program to show output as

```
40 10 parent:40 20 parent:40 30 parent:10 60 parent:20 50 parent:20 70  parent:60
```

Comment: At the line `queue.add(n)`, you have the current node in `n`, and the previous node in `element`.

Comment: That won't help e.g if I have current node 20 the previous node would be 10 but 10 is not the parent of node20

Comment: If you have current node 20, the previous node can't be 10, because 10 and 20 aren't neighbors. In the output 40,10,20, the previous node is 40 for both 10 and 20, because 10 and 20 are the neighbors of 40.

Comment: ok i get what you are saying, you are right but the problem is I'm not printing the current node I'm printing the element when it is popped out from the queue, any solution for that? :/

Comment: The `Node` class would need a `parent` member. That way, you can set the `parent` before putting the `Node` into the queue.

Comment: Even if I add a parent member in the Node class, how can I set the parent before putting the node in the queue?

Comment: `n.parent = element.data`.

Comment: I was doing node.parent = element.data so it was really confusing, anyway thank you so much , Thank you!